# Extract data from NetCDF using a shapefile polygon in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, polygon, netcdf

I need to subset data from a NetCDF using a specific shapefile.  The data are sea surface temperature and ocean color at 1/4 degree resolution.  I have 4 polygons describing the US. Northeast continental shelf large marine ecosystem and it's sub-components that I need to use to extract the data.  I am working with monthly composite files from 1982-2014, so this data extraction routine needs to be automated.  The files are already subsetted to the approximate working area grid of [35, 45, -80, -60].

[image]

Previously, we were converting HDF5 data files to rasters in R and processing them this way, but this method is really inefficient and I am sure there is a better solution in Python using the current NetCDF files.

Thus far I have been using GDAL and Fiona to read in the shapefiles and NetCDF4 to load the data files. I am not sure how to go about subsetting the data.  I found this:

[GDAL for Python: extracting subdomains from NetCDF file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112595/gdal-for-python-extracting-subdomains-from-netcdf-file)

But I don't have the foggiest idea about how to subset a NetCDF file using anything other than a simple bounding box, which these polygons most certainly are not.

Point in polygon routines would probably take an eternity to work, but maybe I could subset the data using a smaller bounding box that is rotated to fit these shapes like this as an initial starting point and then do a point-in-poly search:

[Subsetting a curvilinear netCDF file (ROMS model output) using a lon/lat bounding box.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71630/subsetting-a-curvilinear-netcdf-file-roms-model-output-using-a-lon-lat-boundin)

Any ideas?

EDIT 1:

I just came across the OpenClimateGIS package which seems that it may fit the bill perfectly...  I will have a go with this to see if I can get it to work:
http://ncpp.github.io/ocgis/examples.html#advanced-subsetting

Comment: Your last link in Edit 1 appears to be dead.This appears to be the best substitute: https://www.earthsystemcog.org/projects/openclimategis/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mask NetCDF time series data from a shapefile in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354782/how-to-mask-netcdf-time-series-data-from-a-shapefile-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/pcjericks/py-gdalogr-cookbook/blob/master/raster_layers.rst#clip-a-geotiff-with-shapefile) might be adaptable for your needs.

If you don't mind calling the command line from python, you could do something like `gdalwarp -cutline clip.shp -cl clip -crop_to_cutline input_raster output_raster_clipped.tif`.  `-cwhere` and `-csql` might be more appropriate [gdalwarp options](http://gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) for selecting one of the four polygons for clipping.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585582/how-to-mask-the-specific-array-data-based-on-the-shapefile

What you want to keep in mind is that once you've loaded your NetCDF, you're working with a NumPy array.

What are you trying to output? Summary stats based on the polygon areas?

Anyhow, here's what I'd do:

1. Load your shapefile and get your areas into a supported format (aiming for the matplotlib mask process in the above link sounds good)
2. Load your NetCDF file and get the data into a single X, Y, T numpy array
3. Mask that array using the polygons (one at a time?)
4. Export your summary stats.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rioxarray. Here is an example: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html

```py
import rioxarray
import geopandas

geodf = geopandas.read_file(...)
xds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(...)
clipped = xds.rio.clip(geodf.geometry.apply(mapping), geodf.crs)
```