# Clip a NetCDF file using a shapefile with Python

Tags: python, shapefile, netcdf, matplotlib

I have global net radiation data but I want to extract for my country.  I've loaded the NetCDF but I don't know how to proceed further. The following is a similar question 
([Extract data from netcdf using a shapefile polygon in python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146422/extract-data-from-netcdf-using-a-shapefile-polygon-in-python))  but the answer talks about running from command line but I'm using Spyder.

If someone could help me with the code, I know that I need to use some command like clip or extract but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mask NetCDF time series data from a shapefile in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354782/how-to-mask-netcdf-time-series-data-from-a-shapefile-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use rioxarray. Here is an example: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html

```py
import rioxarray
import geopandas

geodf = geopandas.read_file(...)
xds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(...)
clipped = xds.rio.clip(geodf.geometry.apply(mapping), geodf.crs)
```

Comment: I checked it with a Tiff file and it worked. However, when I checked it with netcdf, I have difficulty with write_crs method to set a proper crs for it.

Comment: What errors do you have? Can you open up a new question with the rioxarray tag and the dataset you are using?

Comment: Sure. Thank you.

Comment: I have written a more detailed answer that deals with my problem (write_crs). I think it can be useful for those who have the same problem. How can I post it here as a second answer? Its seems that the question is closed

Comment: Here is the answer that I was talking about with a new quesion related to it: 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367890/how-to-save-a-clipped-netcdf-data-as-a-new-netcdf-file-in-python

Comment: I'm using the same code to clip some netcdf datasets, from Cepernicus Land Services and I am getting the following error. ```nodata = numpy.dtype(new_dtype).type(original_nodata)
ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy datetime```

Comment: Can you open up an issue on GitHub https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/?