# How to save a clipped NetCDF data as a new NetCDF file in Python?

Tags: raster, clip, netcdf, xarray, rioxarray

I have used `xarray` to clip my NetCDF file‌ (it can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W3W3p0P32kMvOIfQB4kLSDptjQUSyR6-/view?usp=sharing)) by a shapefile (it can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qkVGHmTEp_-pfK3r11mZqNxP3IMWXNqm/view?usp=sharing)). Here is the code:

```
import xarray
import rioxarray
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import mapping

xds = xarray.open_dataset(
    "3B-DAY.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20170216-S000000-E235959.V06.nc4",)

xds = xds[['precipitationCal', 'precipitationCal_cnt']].transpose('time', 'lat', 'lon')

xds.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="lon", y_dim="lat", inplace=True)
xds.rio.write_crs("EPSG:4326", inplace=True)
geodf = geopandas.read_file("NAME_LONG_201.shp")

clipped = xds.rio.clip(geodf.geometry.apply(mapping), geodf.crs)
```

Now, I have a clipped object which is of type: `xarray.Dataset`. How can I save this dataset into a new NetCDF file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xarray.Dataset has a `to_netcdf` method...so it should be `clipped.to_netcdf(path_on_disk)`

http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf.html

Comment: Dear @bcollins, it gives me this error: AttributeError: module 'dask' has no attribute 'base'. I think I have to pip install dask.

Comment: I uninstalled and installed dask again. Still got the above error.

Comment: @Muser hey, which version of dask?

```
import dask
print(dask.__version__)
```

Comment: I used your code, the result is:  2.19.0

Comment: it worked. Thank you. The problem resolved after I reopened my Python IDE.

Before closing the IDE, I installed dask like this: `pip install dask[complete]`

and after installation completed, restarted IDE and it worked

Comment: @Muser, my pleasure...also shameless plug, but you might be interested in Xarray-Spatial: https://github.com/makepath/xarray-spatial

Comment: Seems to be a practical package. Thank you for suggesting it. Do you know if it has other benefits over xarray?

Comment: @Muser Xarray-Spatial contains a bunch of spatial utility functions (crop, trim, slope, zonal stats etc.) on top of xarray.DataArrays...without a GDAL dependency...FYI, I lead the project so feel free to post questions / issues / code review to the github issues area: https://github.com/makepath/xarray-spatial/issues